# Confusion Matrix with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, tensorboard, tensorflow-datasets

I am using finetune AlexNet architecture written by @kratzert on my own dataset which, works properly (I got the code from here: https://github.com/kratzert/finetune_alexnet_with_tensorflow) and I want to figure out how to build confusion matrix from his code. I have tried to use `tf.confusion_matrix(labels, predictions, num_classes)` to build confusion matrix but I can't. I am confused what should be the values for labels and predictions, I mean, I know what should be but each time I feed these value got an error. Can anyone help me on this or have a look at the code (above link) and guide me?

I added these two lines in finetune.py exactly after calculating accuracy to make the labels and the predictions as the number of the class.

```
with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(score, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

**true_class = tf.argmax(y, 1)
predicted_class = tf.argmax(score, 1)**
```

and I have added `tf.confusion_matrix()` inside my session at the very bottom before saving checkpoint of the model

```
for _ in range(val_batches_per_epoch):

    img_batch, label_batch = sess.run(next_batch)


    acc, cost = sess.run([accuracy, loss], feed_dict={x: img_batch,
                                                    y: label_batch,
                                                    keep_prob: 1.})
    test_acc += acc
    test_count += 1

test_acc /= test_count
print("{} Validation Accuracy = {:.4f} -- Validation Loss = {:.4f}".format(datetime.now(),test_acc, cost))

print("{} Saving checkpoint of model...".format(datetime.now()))

**print(sess.run(tf.confusion_matrix(true_class, predicted_class, num_classes)))**

# save checkpoint of the model
checkpoint_name = os.path.join(checkpoint_path,
                               'model_epoch'+str(epoch+1)+'.ckpt')
save_path = saver.save(sess, checkpoint_name)

print("{} Model checkpoint saved at {}".format(datetime.now(),
                                               checkpoint_name))
```

I have tried other places as well but each time I will get an error:

```
Caused by op 'Placeholder_1', defined at:
  File "/home/armin/Desktop/Alexnet_DataPipeline/finetune.py", line 85, in <module>
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, num_classes])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1777, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 4521, in placeholder
    "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3290, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1654, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float and shape [128,3]
```

any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code and error (the important parts, not the full code plz)?

Comment: I have added some part of the code and the lines I added to calculate the confusion matrix and my error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a fairly long piece of code you're referring to, and you did not specify where you put your confusion matrix line.

Just by experience, the most frequent problem with confusion matrices is that [`tf.confusion_matrix()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/confusion_matrix) requires both the labels and the predictions as the number of the class, not as one-hot vectors. In other words, the label and the prediction should be in the form of the number `5` instead of [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ].

In the code you refer to, `y` is in the one-hot format. The output of the network, `score` is a vector, giving the probability of each class. That is also not the required format. You need to do something like

```
true_class = tf.argmax( y, 1 )
predicted_class = tf.argmax( score, 1 )
```

and use those with the confusion matrix like

```
tf.confusion_matrix( true_class, predicted_class, num_classes )
```

(Basically, if you take a look at line 123 of [finetune.py](https://github.com/kratzert/finetune_alexnet_with_tensorflow/blob/master/finetune.py), that has both of those elements for determining accuracy, but they are not saved in separate tensors.)

If you want to keep a running total of confusion matrices of all batches, you just have to add them up - since each cell of the matrix counts the number of examples falling into that category, an element-wise addition creates the confusion matrix for the whole set:

```
cm_running_total = None
cm_nupmy_array = sess.run(tf.confusion_matrix(true_class, predicted_class, num_classes), feed_dict={x: img_batch, y: label_batch, keep_prob: 1.} )
if cm_running_total is None:
    cm_running_total = cm_numpy_array
else:
    cm_running_total += cm_numpy_array
```

Comment: Thanks, I did exactly as you said before wrote my problem here. I edit my post please have a look at it

Comment: Any Idea, where is my mistake?

Comment: Sorry was out for a while. The error says you need to provide the `feed_dict` to the `sess.run()` where you calculate the confusion matrix. So do it like this: `print(sess.run(tf.confusion_matrix(true_class, predicted_class, num_classes), feed_dict={x: img_batch, y: label_batch, keep_prob: 1.}) ))`. Alternatively, you can include the confusion matrix for each batch in the training loop like `acc, cost, conf_m = sess.run([accuracy, loss, tf.confusion_matrix( true_class, predicted_class, num_classes )], feed_dict={x: img_batch, y: label_batch, keep_prob: 1.})`.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are great. Now, I have confusion matrix for every epoch by adding this line `print(sess.run(tf.confusion_matrix(true_class, predicted_class, num_classes), feed_dict={x: img_batch, y: label_batch, keep_prob: 1.}) )` after printing validation accuracy. I mean, I have a confusion matrix of 128 (batch size) in every epoch. I don't have the Confusion matrix of the whole model. I think I have to find the way to accumulate them and get the final confusion matrix which contains all. Can you help me on this as well?

Comment: Added suggested code for running total to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @peter, Sorry for my many questions. What is the `cm_running_total`? because when I added your suggested code to the model I got an error (I added exactly after printing validation accuracy and loss) `NameError: name 'cm_running_total' is not defined` but if I remove the if else statements and instead write `cm_numpy_array += cm_numpy_array` and then `print(cm_numpy_array)` at very bottom of code I have the confusion matrix of 256 if I run the code for 2 epochs is it still correct? or Where and What type should I define `cm_running_total`?

Comment: Added line to initialize `cm_running_total` that holds the running total of the confusion matrix. (`cm_numpy_array += cm_numpy_array` just doubles the value of `cm_numpy_array`...)